# How to use Millman's theorem to solve this question:find the voltage value

Tags: voltage

The question wants me to calculate the Vc

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqlug6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And here is my thinking:

These arrows are the current flowing direction i think,and i think the V1 is 12V,and V6 is 2V. i want to use Millman's theorem to solve this problem

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fojhym.png)</sup>

My formula are as below:

1. \$\frac{12-Va}{8}+\frac{Vb-Va}{5}=\frac{Va-2}{2}\$,that is, \$100+8Vb=33Va\$
2. \$Vc=5+Vb\$,\$Vd=15+Ve\$

unfortunately,i stuck here,does anyone know how to calculate the Vc value by using the Millman's theorem ??

Comment: doesn't Millman's theorem only concern itself with current sources, but you have voltage sources?

Comment: Also, the right-hand loop has only one reference point, so nothing right of, including R3, matters to the left hand loop? Considering  this and my above comment, I'd assume you're not reproducing your problem correctly, and thus sadly vote to close as in need of further clarification.

Comment: @MarcusMüller YOU always like to vote to close,lol

Comment: If an experienced user tells you on multiple questions that they aren't up to the mandatory standards of this site, then either that experienced user is fundamentally wrong, or your questions tend to be of low quality. Interpretation is up to you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Wikipedia tells me it is voltage sources.

Answer (score 0):

Homework, only guidance will be given.

The right half has no connection to the left half except R3. Thus there's no current in R3 => Vc=Va+5V. The situation would be different if there were for ex. a GND connection in the right half of the circuit, but there isn't, so the voltages at points b,c,d and e ride on what sources V1 and V6 generate to point a.

Calculate Va with Millman's formula. Use source voltages V1 and V6 and resistances R1 and R2. Then add 5V. That's your Vc calculated by applying Millman's theorem as a part of the calculations.

Comment: The right half has no connection to the left half except R3. Thus there's no current in R3,i don't understand,if R3 is the connection,why won't the current flow to the R3?

Comment: @shineele there's no loop, the right half of the circuit is for the left half like a wire which has only one end connected. The wire contains parts   R4, R5, V4, V5 but they play only among themselves. V1, V6, R1 and R2 see nothing through R3 about the existence of R4,R5, V5, V6